# How to fix href link on Ajax loaded content with vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So basically, I'm loading and inserting html to a div element on my homepage. It all works well except that I've realised my regular href link just won't work. When I hover the URL appears on the bottom of Chrome as usual, but when I click, nothing happens.

For what I've seen, it seems like click events might not work properly on dynamically added elements?

The issue is, I've only seen jQuery solutions for this, and, frankly, I'm not even sure if this is the issue at all.

Any ideas?

PS: http://jsfiddle.net/8hz1Lubr/

```
// -------------------------- get the elements ----------------------- //
const deskbar = document.querySelector('#deskbar');
const screen = document.querySelector('#desktop');
const menuLink = document.querySelector('#primaryNav');
const tabsList = document.querySelector('#tabsList');
const clock = document.getElementById('theTime');
const desktop = document.querySelector('#contentarea');


// -------------------------- create events -------------------------- //
  screen.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
  tabsList.addEventListener('click', activateTab);
  menuLink.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
  menuLink.addEventListener('click', generateTab);

// -------------------------- open windows --------------------------- //
function openWindow(e) {
  let windows = document.querySelectorAll('.window');
  let openWindows = [];

  windows.forEach(function(theWindow){
    openWindows.push(theWindow.getAttribute('data-window'));
  });

  if(e.target.classList.contains('menuLink') && !openWindows.includes(e.target.getAttribute('data-link'))) {
    let newWindow =`<div class="window" id="${e.target.getAttribute('data-link')}" data-window="${e.target.getAttribute('data-link')}">
  <header class="header"></header>
  <span class="close"></span>
  <div class="headerContent">
    ${e.target.innerText}
    <span class="minimize"></span>
  </div>
  <article>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
</div>`;
desktop.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newWindow);
fetchPage(e.target.href, e.target.getAttribute('data-link'));
  }
  windows = document.querySelectorAll('.window');

  // create add event listener for each new window
  windows.forEach(function(theWindow){
theWindow.addEventListener('click', closeWindow);
theWindow.addEventListener('click', closeTab);

if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 960px)").matches) {
  theWindow.getElementsByClassName('headerContent')[0].onmousedown = function(event) {
    let shiftX = event.clientX - theWindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - theWindow.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    deactivateAllWindows();

    theWindow.classList.add('activeWindow');
    theWindow.style.position = 'absolute';
    theWindow.style.zIndex = 15;

    desktop.append(theWindow);
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    // centers the ball at (pageX, pageY) coordinates
    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
      theWindow.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
      theWindow.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }

    // move the window on mousemove
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    // drop the window, remove unneeded handlers
    theWindow.onmouseup = function() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      theWindow.onmouseup = null;
    };
  };
  theWindow.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };
}
  });

  e.preventDefault();
}

// -------------------------- fetch html content --------------------- //
function fetchPage(url, attribute) {
  let windows = document.querySelectorAll('.window');
  fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    windows.forEach(function(theWindow) {
      theWindow.style.zIndex = 14;
  theWindow.classList.remove('activeWindow');
});
windows.forEach(function(theWindow) {
  if(theWindow.getAttribute('data-window') == attribute) {
    if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 960px)").matches) {
      let randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 20 + 1)) + 20;
      let randomWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 20 + 1)) + 20;

      theWindow.style.zIndex = 15;

      theWindow.style.top = randomHeight + '%';
      theWindow.style.left = randomWidth + '%';

      setTimeout(function(){
        theWindow.style.opacity = 1;
      }, 125);
    }

    theWindow.classList.add('activeWindow');

    let content = theWindow.querySelector('.content');
    content.innerHTML = body;
  }
});
  });
}
```

Comment: Two comments - first - you should show the code you have tried and second - you should investigate event delegation for the click handler binding the event to an element that is present in the DOM before the dynamically created elements are inserted.

Comment: I've added the relevant JS code and a link to a JS Fiddle with both the full JS and the HTML.
I'm pretty sure I've used Event Delegation, but maybe I don't fully understand it.

Comment: "For what I've seen, it seems like click events might not work properly on dynamically added elements?" - Nope. Not even remotely true. The mistake lies elsewhere.